# Create multiple databases sqlite with phonegap on android

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova

I'm trying to create multiple databases on same app with apache cordova 2.5 on android 2.2 but I can't. When I create the second database, window.openDatabase returns null.
Is there any way to do this?

thanks,
regards!

Comment: Why would you do that exactly?

Comment: This is the fastest way to classify user data. When the user logging into app, it will open the correct db. The correct way would be add a user-id column in a few tables and modify the queries to filter it, but it would take me a long time, because the app is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a long time ago. But now, with phonegap 2.9, I am not having this problem anymore.

If updating to a new version of phonegap is not an option for you, you could try using this plugin: [SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-Android).

They have an explanation on how to use multiple dbs [here](http://brodyspark.blogspot.com.br/2012/12/improvements-to-phonegap-sqliteplugin.html).

(By the way, phonegap 3 introduced a new and better workflow, you should try it out - [more info here](http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/07/19/adobe-phonegap-3.0-released/))